Laplace's equation in Polar coordinates on the semi-annular domain
Solve the following boundary value problems for the Laplace equation on the semi-
annular domain $D = { 1 < x^2 + y^2 < 2,\; y > 0 }:$
$ u(x, y) = 0, x^2 + y^2 = 1\; \text{or}\; 2, u(x, 0) = 0, x > 0, u(x, 0) = 1, x < 0 $
My effort:
We need to solve:
$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \theta^2}=0
$$
With
$$ u(r,0) =0,u(r,\pi) = 1, u(1,\theta) = 0, u(\sqrt{2},\theta) = 0 \;\; , 1 \le r \le 2 \;\; ,  0 \le \theta \le \pi   $$
and also $u(r,\theta ) = u(r,\theta + 2\pi)$
Using separation of variables we have $$u(r,\theta) = v(r) w(\theta) $$ and as we learned in class
For $v(r) $ we have, as we learned in class the following ODE $$ r^2v_{rr} + rv_r  -\lambda v = 0 $$ and the solution for $\lambda >0=\omega^2$ is $$ v(r) = Cr^{\omega} + Dr^{-\omega} $$ where $\omega =n \;\; n=1,2 \ldots $
Using boundary conditions:
$ u(1,\theta) = 0 \implies v(1) = 0 \implies C=-D $
$ u(\sqrt{2},\theta) = 0 \implies v(\sqrt{2}) = 0 \implies C2^{n/2} - C2^{-n/2} =0  \implies C( 2^{n/2} - 2^{-n/2}) =0  $
But the only solution is $C=D=0$
For $\lambda=0$ we get $v(r) = C + D\ln(r) $
$ u(1,\theta) = 0 \implies v(1) = 0 \implies C =0$
$ u(\sqrt{2},\theta) = 0 \implies v(\sqrt{2}) = 0 \implies D =0$
So we could not find any eigenvalues so the solution should be the trivial solution but it does not satisfy the boundary conditions and therefore no solution.
Is my conclusion correct ?

The boundary conditions on $u$ are contradictory. For instance $u(-1,0)$ has to be equal to $0$ by the first condition and to $-1$ by the last condition.

I just fixed this typo

Alex, this is from the Olver,Peter J book so there might be a typo in the source. I think we can assume that all the boundaries have value of zero except on (x,0)where the value is 1  for x<0

Physically, you can expect there to be a solution. From an electrostatic perspective, it is as if you ground the three sides of the annulus and impose a voltage along an insulated conducting electrode on the side $y=0, x>0$. You could even make it in real life. In the following, I'll write $R = \sqrt2>1$ the outer radius of the annulus and $\Theta = \pi<2\pi$ the opening of the annulus.
The easiest way to construct a solution is to use a conformal transformation. The idea is that harmonic functions are preserved by conformal mapping. You can map your semi-annulus to a rectangle, which is easier done using the complex exponential with $z=x+iy$. Your domain is the image of the rectangle of vertices $0,\ln R,\ln R+i\Theta,i\Theta$. By cartesian separation of variables, you can solve the Laplace equation on a rectangle with specified value on one edge. This gives you your solution to your original problem.
This brings insight to your original problem. The main issue is that you were considering only $\lambda\geq 0$ solutions whereas the relevant solutions are precisely $\lambda<0$. Indeed, $\omega=il$ is a pure imaginary and your boundary conditions impose:
$$
C+D = 0 \\
CR^\omega+DR^{-\omega} = 0
$$
The system is degenerate iff
$$
R^{2il} = 1
$$
i.e.
$$
l_n = \frac{n\pi}{\ln R} \\
v_n  \propto (r^{il_n}-r^{-il_n})
$$
with $n\in\mathbb N^*$. For later convenience, I will choose the normalisation:
$$
v_n = \sin(l_n\ln r)
$$
This gives the corresponding $\lambda_n = -l_n^2$. You can now solve the angular part:
$$
w_n''=l_n^2w \\
w_n(0)=1 \quad w_n(\Theta)=0
$$
so:
$$
w_n = \frac{\sinh(l_n(\Theta-\theta))}{\sinh(l_n\Theta)}
$$
Your general solution can thus be written as:
$$
u = \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n v_n(r)w_n(\theta)
$$
The $C_n$ are determined by the inhomogeneous boundary condition at $\theta=0$:
$$
1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n v_n(r)
$$
As usual, you use the fact that the $v_n$ are an orthonormal basis, you can compute the coefficients:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12 \delta_{mn} &= \int_1^R v_mv_n\frac{dr}r \\
C_n &= \int_1^R v_n\frac{dr}r \\
&= \frac2{\pi n}(1-(-1)^n) \\
1 &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac4{\pi (2n+1)}v_{2n+1}(r) \\
u &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac4{\pi (2n+1)}v_{2n+1}(r)w_{2n+1}(\theta) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac4{\pi (2n+1)\sinh(\pi(2n+1)\Theta/\ln R)} \sin(\pi(2n+1)\log_R r)\sinh\left(\pi(2n+1)\frac{\Theta-\theta}{\ln R}\right)
\end{align}
$$
You'll notice that using the conformal mapping, the separated basis functions in cartesian coordinates precisely become the new separated functions that I have computed. Just as in the former case, you can sum the series by using elementary functions.
Hope this helps.

Indeed I need to consider $\lambda < 0$ but in that case I think I can just do : For $\lambda <0 = - \omega^2 $ we have the solution $$ v(r) = C\sin(\omega \ln(r)) + D\cos(\omega \ln(r))$$
$ v(1)=0 \implies D =0 $ and $ v(\sqrt{2})=0 \implies \sin(1/2 \omega \ln(2) ) =0 \implies 1/2 \omega \ln(2)= n \pi \implies \omega= \frac{2n \pi}{\ln{2}} $ which is the start of the solution because we just  found all the eigenvalues.

This is my latest effort
For $\lambda <0 = - \omega^2 $ we have the solution $$ v(r) = C\sin(\omega \ln(r)) + D\cos(\omega \ln(r))$$
$ v(1)=0 \implies D =0 $ and $ v(\sqrt{2})=0 \implies \sin(1/2 \omega \ln(2) ) =0 \implies 1/2 \omega \ln(2)= n \pi \implies \omega= \frac{2n \pi}{\ln{2}} $
and therefore $$ v(r)= C\sin(\frac{2\pi n \ln {r}}{\ln{2}}) \;\; n=1,2 \ldots $$
On the other hand for $\lambda < 0 $  we have
$$ w(\theta ) = A\cosh(\omega \theta )  + B  \sinh(\omega \theta ) $$
$$ w(0) = 0 \implies A =0 \implies w(\theta) = B\sinh(\frac{2\pi n \theta}{\ln{2}}) $$
and therefore
$$ u(r,\theta) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sinh(\frac{2\pi n \theta}{\ln{2}}) \sin(\frac{2\pi n \ln {r}}{\ln{2}}) 
\implies u(r=e^z,\theta) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sinh(\frac{2\pi n \theta}{\ln{2}}) \sin(\frac{2\pi n z}{\ln{2}}) 
$$
and now
$$ u(z,\pi) = 1 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} B_n \sinh(\frac{2\pi^2 n }{\ln{2}})  \sin(\frac{2\pi n {z}}{\ln{2}}) $$
where $ z $  in the interval  $   [0, \frac{1}{2} \ln{2}] $ matching the domain of $r$ which is $[1, \sqrt{2}]$.
We can view this series as a Fourier series of the odd extension of $1$ on $[-\frac{1}{2} ln{2}, \frac{1}{2} ln{2} ]$ and we get   :
\begin{align*}
 B_n \sinh\left(\frac{2\pi^2 n}{\ln{2}}\right) &= 2\frac{2}{\ln{2}} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2} \ln{2}} 1*\sin\left(\frac{2\pi n z}{\ln{2}}\right) \, dz \\
 &= \frac{4}{\ln{2}} \cdot \frac{\ln{2}}{2 \pi n} - \cos\left(\frac{2\pi n z}{\ln{2}}\right)\Bigg|_0^{\frac{1}{2} \ln{2}} \\
 &= 0 \quad \text{when } n \text{ is even} \\
 &= \frac{4}{\pi n} \quad \text{when } n \text{ is odd}
\end{align*}
$$ B_n =  \frac{4}{\pi n  \sinh\left(\frac{2\pi^2 n}{\ln{2}}\right)}
$$ when $n$ is odd otherwise $0$.
And we get
$$
u(r,\theta)=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{4}{\pi (2n+1)  \sinh\left(\frac{2\pi^2 (2n+1)}{\ln{2}}\right)} \sinh(\frac{2\pi (2n+1) \theta}{\ln{2}}) \sin(\frac{2\pi (2n+1) \ln r}{\ln{2}}) 
$$

Let $v(r,\theta):=u(r,\theta)-\frac{\theta}{\pi}$. It satisfies the same equation as $u$,
$$
\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial r^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial v}{\partial r} + \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial \theta^2}=0, \tag{1}
$$
but with different boundary conditions:
\begin{align}
v(r,0)&=v(r,\pi)=0 & (1<r<\sqrt{2}), \tag{2.1} \\
v(1,\theta)&=v(\sqrt{2},\theta)=-\frac{\theta}{\pi} & (0<\theta<\pi). \tag{2.2}
\end{align}
Using separation of variables, it's not difficult to show that the general solution to $(1)$ that satisfies the boundary conditions $(2.1)$ is
$$
v(r,\theta)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(A_nr^{n}+B_nr^{-n})\sin(n\theta). \tag{3}
$$
The coefficients $A_n$ and $B_n$ are determined by the boundary conditions $(2.2)$:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(A_n+B_n)\sin(n\theta)
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(A_n2^{n/2}+B_n2^{-n/2})\sin(n\theta)=-\frac{\theta}{\pi}
$$
$$
\implies A_n+B_n=A_n2^{n/2}+B_n2^{-n/2}=-\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{\theta}{\pi}\sin(n\theta)\,d\theta
=\frac{2(-1)^n}{n\pi}. \tag{4}
$$
Solving for $A_n$ and $B_n$ we obtain
$$
A_n=\frac{2(-1)^n}{n\pi\left(1+2^{n/2}\right)}, \qquad
B_n=\frac{2(-1)^n2^{n/2}}{n\pi\left(1+2^{n/2}\right)}. \tag{5}
$$
Finally, it follows from $(3)$ and $(5)$ that
$$
u(r,\theta)=\frac{\theta}{\pi}+v(r,\theta)=\frac{\theta}{\pi}+
\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\left(\frac{r^n+2^{n/2}r^{-n}}{1+2^{n/2}}\right)\sin(n\theta). \tag{6}
$$

I'm not clear how you end up not having $log(r)$ in the solution.

Why should I have $\log r$ in my solution?

Because  separation of variables $u(r,\theta) = v(r) w(\theta) $ gives    $ r^2v'' + rv'  -\lambda v = 0 $  and for $ \lambda < 0 = - \omega^2$  we get $ v(r) = C\sin(\omega \ln(r)) + D\cos(\omega \ln(r))$

Notice that I defined a variable $v=u-\theta/\pi$ that vanishes at $\theta=0$ and $\theta=\pi$. Doing separation of variables for (my) $v$, the angular function $w(\theta)$ cannot be made to vanish at those points if $\lambda<0$ (unless $w(\theta)=0$).

I see - I still don't see what is wrong with my solution ("This is my latest effort") where I get an expression of $u(r,\theta)$ that includes $log(r)$
